# How to change video orientation to portrait in default camera view in Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

We are working on a video recording application.
Users can record videos and upload them. We wish to restrict portrait videos. We plan to record a video intro, don't allow the video to be show in "landscape" mode. It should force the user to only use portrait mode (taller vertically)

```
private fun openVideo() {

    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val videoFileName = "$timeStamp.mp4"
    pictureVideoPath = "$videoFilePath/$videoFileName"
    val file = File(pictureVideoPath)

    val outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireActivity(),
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
        file)

    Log.v("OutputVideoUri", outputFileUri.toString())

    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, mRequestVideoCapture)
}
```